# Simple check for character in char array in C

Tags: c

I am new to C. This code runs on a Flyport module and compiles on their own IDE but I should think my error should be easy to spot for anyone familiar with C.

I can't get this code to compile despite changing almost everything, what am I doing wrong?

```
char string_serial[50]="starting Value";    

if (string_serial[0] = "*")
        {   

            UARTWrite(2,"First Char OK");
            UARTWrite(2,"\r\n");

            else 

            UARTWrite(2,"First Char NOT OK");
            UARTWrite(2,"\r\n");

        }
```

If it's not obvious I am trying to check if character 0 in the array is *.

Thanks

Comment: Line 2: "\*" isn't a character, but a string (`const char [2]` to be exact). Use single quotes for characters => '\*'.
Line 3: you have a braces problem, the correct syntax is => `if (/* condition /*) { /* code if true */ } else { /* code if false /* }`

Comment: You have to use == and * should be in single quotes like 

    if (string_serial[0] == '*')
and also the braces are to be kept in proper positions.
    
    if{/*if block*/} else {/*else block*/}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax for if/else conditions is wrong

The syntax should be

```
 if(condition)
  {
  }

  else
  {
  }
```

For your specific code it should be

```
if (string_serial[0] == '*')
        {   

            UARTWrite(2,"First Char OK");
            UARTWrite(2,"\r\n");
         }

else 
        {
            UARTWrite(2,"First Char NOT OK");
            UARTWrite(2,"\r\n");

        }
```

The `=` operator is assignment, it assigns the value (returning true when successful). What you need is `==` (for comparing).

Also use single quotes for characters as shown in the code above.

Comment: I think that is all good but I still get an error "syntax error at end of input" but maybe this is specific to the Flyport. It is great here I get an answer in 2 minutes, on the Flyport forum I can wait a week! Many thanks

Comment: @Simon_A: `syntax error at end of input` is mostly because of unmatched flower brackets, check in your program whether each opened `{` has a matching `}`

Answer (score 2):

You should replace double quotes with single quotes around `"*"`, and use `==`:

```
if (string_serial[0] == '*')
```

A single character enclosed in single quotes means "a character"; a single character enclosed in double quotes means "a one-character C string".

A single `=` means "assignment"; a double  `==` means "compare".

Comment: Perhaps, changing `=` to `==` as well.

Answer (score 1):

`''` is for a single `char`, but `""` is for strings. The following line should work.

```
if (string_serial[0] == '*')
```

Answer (score 1):

You if structure is not correct

try this:

```
char string_serial[50]="starting Value";    

if (string_serial[0] == '*')
{   

   UARTWrite(2,"First Char OK");
}

else {

  UARTWrite(2,"First Char NOT OK");
  UARTWrite(2,"\r\n");

}
```

You need to change `=` to `==` and also get `else block` out of the `if block`